# Wamp Server icon is red

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I recently installed wamp server 2.2 in my system. But the icon is red for some weird reason. 
I am able to see phpmyadmin but when I open MySQL(http://localhost/phpmyadmin) it says

MySQL said:

> #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not     correctly configured)

I checked the task manager and I can only see wampmanager.exe running. 
I tested port 80 and it says

> Your port 80 is actually used by:
>   server:  Apache/2.2.17(Wind32) PHP/5.3.5

Also in Apache>Service start/resume service, stop service, restart service are disabled.

Please tell me what is the issue.

Comment: Not a programming question. Might be better suited for http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 31):

Click WampServer Icon.

- Apache > Service > Install Service
- Apache > Service > Start/Resume Service
- MySQL > Service > Install Service
- MySQL > Service > Start/Resume Service

Comment: is it a service by default? like i'd have thought maybe it doesn't start with windows by default and only starts when wamp is started?

Comment: @barlop Thats 4 year old answer, Services only Start when WAMP server started.

Comment: is it no longer a windows service.. for example, if you look in services.msc or like the other answer says, if you loook in task manager services tab, do you still see the service there?

Comment: @barlop now i am using macbook, so when i have windows system/laptop, will check and let you know.

Comment: I finally managed to get wamp installed and not red, and yeah it is.. I see it in services.msc  wampmysqld64 and wampapache64

Comment: Good, got me to Orange. Onto the next problem.

Comment: @Andrew what is your problem may I know it?

Answer (score 6):

**Solution that worked for me:**

1. Access services.msc (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services);
2. Find all the services that start with `"wamp"`. In my case: `wampapache64` and `wampmysqld64`;
3. Double click on each of them and set the start-up type as: `"automatic"`;
4. Restart all services of wamp, by clicking once on its tray icon and selecting the option `"Restart All Services"`.

I don't know why, but, somehow, the services start-up types where marked as `"Disabled"`. Maybe some other software made it without my consent. Because of that, the **Wamp** was with a **red icon**, but showing **online** when hoovering the mouse over it.

[image: wamp red icon but online cause]

Comment: Thanks this got me from red icon to yellow icon

Answer (score 4):

Well I tried them all but dint work.
After few trials the following worked for me.

Start task manager open **'Services'** tab and click "**Services..**" at the bottom. A Services window shows up.

Now search for **wampmysqld** and double click on it. Just make startup type as automatic and start the service by clicking start at Service status section down there. You can see you wamp icon yellow.

Go back to the services window and do same for **wampapache**. Double click on it. Just make startup type as automatic and start the service by clicking start at Service status section down there. Wamp icon turns in to green and now localhost can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Some other programs conflict with wampserver, I don't know them all by heart, but I know when skype is running wampserver can't go online.

Comment: I am not using skype. How do I find out if it is conflicting with any other program? Port 80 is being used by apache.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing WAMP 2.1 I also tried each and everything, but install WAMP 2.1, refrain from 2.2,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.1/

Some of the posts i read also suggest installing WAMP 2.1 !

Have a gr8 time!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you have to star all the three services automatic then you get the green color of the wamp server symbol that means all thee three services running sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `windows IIS` as well?
If yes please remove that from add/remove windows components.

If not try this [link](http://zourbuth.com/2002-the-server-is-not-responding-or-the-local-mysql-servers-socket-is-not-correctly-configured/)

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL log file Click wamp icon>MySQL MySQL log. Check the last lines of the file. If you see:

> [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
> [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
> [ERROR] Aborting

Open Administrative tools of windows go to services search and stop MySQL service. Then restart all services of wamp.

Also a lot of applications (more common skype) use 80 port to communicate. So you might have to change the port of your localhost.

Oh and dont forget to clear your browser cache. This might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If that will help someone:
Run from "Services" wampapache64 and wampmysql64 manually. Then run wamp.

Perhaps you remove this services from autoload in msconfig.

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because SQL Server process are running in the background.
Goto Control Panel and Click on Adminstrative Tools and then goto Services. Disable all the services that start with SQL Server. Restart the server, it should turn Orange now. Check whether the Start/Resume Service in Apache->Service is green or not. In case it's not green it means that the Apache server is running normally. So now the issue is with MYSQL. Again goto Control Panel->Adminstrative tools->Services, Disable the MYSQL 56 process. Restart the Server. It should turn green now.

I have written a blog which further explains the problem and might help you resolve it.[Solving the WAMP Issue](https://rajiv2309.wordpress.com/2016/03/05/fixing-the-wamp-issue-when-the-tray-icon-is-red/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have something listening on port 80 with pid 4 then that can cause wamp tray icon to stay red, and it may be this service causing it.

This service, if you have it running would be a culprit, (I guess it's ms sql rather than mysql so wouldn't be something left over from a wamp installation, but perhaps some kind of port clash between ms sql and mysql).

Open Services.msc and stop this service "Sql server reporting services(MSSQLSERVER)"

[image]

Other things you can try, are end tasking skype 'cos that uses port 80.. (though could be made to use another port),   could try ending a service called web deployment.. could try going to "programs and features"..turn windows features on and off..and untick "internet information services"(IIS).  Some have suggested trying net stop http(though some mention that might stop more than you want).  None of that is what solved it for me though.

What solved it for me was that that service was running and so I had to stop that service.  It must be that the wamp uninstall left that service running.  I could see (from `netstat -aon | find ":80"`) something listening on port 80 and it just coming up with the system process pid 4.

So after uninstalling WAMP and seeing something listening on port 80, and having trouble installing it 'cos each time I tried I got the red icon. So I uninstalled WAMP again but this time I then stopped that service.. Then I was able to reinstall WAMP and it worked, green icon.